# windows server 2008 r2 - Script on server needs interactive user input

Tags: backup, powershell, robocopy, user, interaction

i have a small script running which listens for a specific ip to get online in the network. (for a robocopy job)
I have split this into two things:

If the client is connected via vpn, ask the user if he is ready for the backup.
If the client is connected locally, just run the backup.

Well, one thing would be to run a script in the same way on the client itself. This would make an interaction possible.
It is not exactly what i have in mind, so...

Another thing i had in mind is to invoke the powershell commands on the clients machine, to start a process on the clients machine?

I appreciate any thoughts on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no native solution to this problem.
I suggest to either use a third party application or go the 'hacky' way and invoke a local script on target client to temporary store your desired information and process further.

[This thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/d4ccfe4b-d9d0-49c7-90b6-26344a1ad3fa/need-help-sending-dialog-to-remote-computer-and-saving-results?forum=winserverpowershell) may be useful.
Hope that helps.